# When using the buildForm->add() function in Symfony2, What are the acceptable options?

Tags: php, symfony

I have looked through the documentation and unless i've missed it I'm not able to find anything explaining what the official $options are for the buildForm->add() function in Symfony2.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->add('fieldname1');        
    $builder->add('fieldname2', new formObjectType(), $arrayOptions);

}
```

Taking the code above, what options would be passed in as an array for the second field.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This same question has bothered me as well. The default options are written inside respective [type classes](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type). Let's take [`DateType`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php) as an example.

[`DateType::getDefaultOptions()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php#L157) lists all the default options, if you don't define them yourself. In addition we have [`DateType::getAllowedOptionValues()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php#L179) - it seems to define which values are valid for certain options.

Note that all of the classes extend `AbstractType` and in addition to this inheritance every "type" implements [`FormTypeInterface::getParent()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.php#L33). For `DateType` the parent is [`FieldType`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/FieldType.php). `FieldType` is obviously the parent class for most fields and it has a couple of default options defined as well. I'm guessing all these options get merged together upon calling out a specific form type.

Comment: In my testing, in Symfony 2.5, the options you pass in, are NOT merged with the custom options you set in AbstractType#setDefaultOptions(). I don't if I'm doing something wrong, but this is a big problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

These options are passed to the field type, in your case `formObjectType`. So, it really depends on what options are accepeted by this field. For example, say you want to pass a option to tell the `formObjectType` to display or not a given field. You could do something like this:

```
// Application/AcmeBundle/Form/Type/FormObjectType.php
class FormObjectType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->add('name', 'text');
        if ($options['display_custom_field'] === true) {
            $this->add('name_custom', 'text');
        }

    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'display_custom_field' => false,
        );
    }
}

// Application/AcmeBundle/Controller/FormController.php
class FormController extends Controller 
{
    public function createForm($object)
    {
        return $this->getFormFactory()->create(new FormObjectType(), $object, array(
            'display_custom_field' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function customAction() 
    {
        $form = $this->createForm();

        // Code here ...
    }
}
```

If the option is the in the array passed or not array is passed at all, the default value if set in the `formObjectType`. So, this array is used to customize the options a given type is expected. This also work with built-in type like `text`, `date`, etc.

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Matt

P.S. You should start your class name with an upper case letter: `FormObjectType` instead of `formObjectType` to differentiate variables and methods from class names. This is only a suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks Matt, My question probably wasn't entirely clear.  The array of $options passed into the buildForm function seemed pretty clear, what i was after was the options you would pass per field as you call $this->add('foo', 'text', $options). I appreciate the response though, probably helpful for someone.